# How to break axios promise with conditional?

Tags: javascript, promise, vue.js, axios

In a vue.js app, I have this part that deals with the fetching data for unlimited pagination:

```
fetchData() {
      this.loading = true
      this.page++;
      axios.get(this.BASE_URL + '/api/jokes/'+'?page='+this.page).then( response => 
            this.jokes = response.data)
           .then( if (this.jokes.length == null) {throw new Error("end of pagination")} )
           .catch(function (error) {
           });      
     document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
     this.loading = false;    
  };
```

I want to stop rendering empty `jokes` and break out of the function  if the response is empty. As you can see in the code abouve, I put a conditional in another then, but get error on the `if`:

```
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (169:20)
```

So I'm wondering what's the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: Add brackets `{}` in `then` callback.

Comment: @alexmac can you elaborate how? I'm new to js stuff.

Comment: You don't have a function expression around you `if `statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem in your code is that your `then` callback defined incorrectly.

```
.then(() => if (this.jokes.length == null) {throw new Error("end of pagination")})
```

You need to wrap it with brackets `{}`:

```
.then(() => {
  if (this.jokes.length == null) {
     throw new Error("end of pagination")
  }
})
```

Another problem is that, you defined one additional `then` callback and incorrectly validates that `jokes` array is an empty (instead of `this.jokes.length === null`, validate that it's defined and it's length equal to zero):

```
.then(response => { 
   let jokes = response.data;
   if (!jokes || jokes.length === 0) {
     throw new Error("end of pagination");
   }
   this.jokes = jokes;
});
```

Comment: This results in `Uncaught (in promise) Error: end of pagination` even at the first page. So I guess the conditional needs to be rewritten.

Comment: Are you sure that `jokes` is not empty at the first page? Add `console.log(jokes)` in the top of then callback.

Comment: Yes, there are jokes up to 6th page.

Comment: Btw, in the top of `fetchData` you increment the page, so it starts from 1 (if it was 0), not from 0.

Comment: `console.log(jokes)` prints something or not?

Comment: The jokes are rendered on template. I can see them. page is initiated at -1.

Comment: Could you just insert `console.log(jokes)` and watch, what it contains, when you got `end of pagination` error.

Answer (score 1):

You have to `attach` a `callback` function to `then` **promise**.

```
fetchData() {
  this.loading = true
  this.page++;
       axios.get(this.BASE_URL + '/api/jokes/'+'?page='+this.page).then(function( response){
          this.jokes = response.data;
          return this.jokes;
       }).then(function(response){
          if (!response || response.length == 0) {
            throw new Error("end of pagination")
          } 
       }).catch(function (error) {

       });        
   document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
   this.loading = false;    
}
```

or use an `arrow` function and `wrap` the condition with `{}`.

```
.then(()=>{
      if (this.jokes.length == null) {
          throw new Error("end of pagination")
      } 
    }
})
```

Comment: This removes the error. But I still get a last page that contains nothing, which is exactly what I want to avoid. Any idea how do so?

Comment: @Karlom, yes, just return the data in first `then`.